# Return index as number inside an if-statement

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

I’m trying to get an index from a table in protractor using typescript. I got so far that I am able to print the single index out, depending on the string. 
The next step is to return the index as a number to use it other functions.

The table looks like that:

```
<ul class="items">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried a lot of combinations like returning the index at the end, return without resolving promises…
Deleting the first return, results in an error: “A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value”

```
async GetTableIndex(): Promise<number> {
    return element.all(by.css('.items li')).each(async(element, index) => {
        if(await element.getText() === “Third”){
            console.log(index); //prints out 3 as expected
            return new Promise(resolve => resolve(index));
        }
        //else ?
    });
}
```

Expected result for Console.log(this.GetTableIndex()); is 3

Current result is:
[undefined,
undefined,
undefined]

How I can return only the number? 
I am new to TypeScript and Protractor, maybe I used just the .each wrongly or promises or everything at once?

Comment: What do you get with `console.log(await this.GetTableIndex())`?

Comment: Sadly still the same, undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`element.all().each()` can only return a `Promise<null>` value.

Approach 1:

```
GetTableIndex(txt: string): Promise<number> {
  return element.all(by.css('.items li')).getText().then((txts)=>{
    return txts.indexOf(txt);
  });
}
```

Approach 2:

```
GetTableIndex(txt: string): Promise<number> {
  return element.all(by.css('.items li')).map((item)=>{
    return item.getText();
  })
  .then((txts)=>{
    return txts.indexOf(txt);
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. 

For the first approach there is an error: TypeError: txts.index is not a function

The second approach has also an error: Property 'index' does not exist on type '{}[]'

I've tried a lot with your examples, still not the nicest solution, but it works. (see my edit on this post)

Comment: I make a typo.  `txts.index` should be `txts.indexOf`